# How to send an image in my citrus HTTP request?

Tags: java, image, spring-boot, continuous-integration, citrus-framework

I am trying to send an image.jpeg in a citrus behavior class, and in my case, I receive in response a blank page and it's not what I expected.

Here my code below :

```
    @Override
    public void run(ScenarioRunner scenario) {

        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icon").toURI());
            List<Path> paths = Files.walk(path).filter(Files::isRegularFile).collect(Collectors.toList());
            int returnThisIcon = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, paths.size());      
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(paths.get(returnThisIcon).toString());
            scenario
            .http()
            .send(action -> {
                try {
                    action
                    .response(status)
                    .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
                    .payload(""+ StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(in));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        }catch(URISyntaxException ue) {
            ue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4000, 150000);

        try {
            long sleepTime = (randomNum);
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error("JobSleeping and thread sleep", e);
        }






    }
```

I tested my HTTP request with Postman and I have OK results with 200 code and with a body of an image, but the image is a tiny square icon. You can see that citrus framework send the HTTP request to receive a jpeg image format, but in response, the image is all black with a tiny icon. Instead of having my image jpeg. Can anyone help me to return the picture I need with citrus?

Answer (score 1):

In your sample you convert the binary icon data to String which basically destroyed the data so that icon can not be displayed as image anymore.

If you want to send the binary data as is you need to use the message() method instead of payload(). Here you can provide a message object and directly give the input stream as message content.